# facebook request dialog not returning repsonse

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following code displaying the request dialog. The function sends the requests to the users I select but the problem is that it DOES NOT RETURN THE SELECTED USERS IDS

```
$('#request_btn').click(function(){send_request()});

function send_request()
{
var message = 'Bla Bla';
var title   = 'Bla Bla'

FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: message,
        title: title,
        max_recipients: 20
},
function (response)
{
    if (response && response.request_ids)
    {
        alert('success')
    }

});

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be returning the request IDs, not the user IDs, are you sure that's not happening?
The example at http://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/apprequests is working fine for me

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry that is what I meant. Anyway I just created another app and changed the app id and it worked. For some reason it was not working with the one I already had. 
Thanks anyway.